# Custom seekbar not showing smoothly

Tags: android, seekbar

As shown in the image below  the seekbar line is chopped or dotted and I don't know why.

[image]

Here is the veiw:

```
 android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1"
        android:max="0"
        android:maxHeight="3dp"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:progress="100"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/scrubber_progress_horizontal_holo_light"
        android:thumb="@drawable/scrubber_control_selector_holo_light" />
```

Comment: You have to check your custom drawable file.

Comment: yes. its auto generated from  http://android-holo-colors.com/